# check the available slots/resources before spawning MPI processes

Tags: mpi

I need ,before spawning a number of workers processes as shown below, to check if this number is available so that the below code will not crash if the requested slots is not available.

```
   int numworkers = settings.Parallelism + 1; //omp_get_num_procs();
    MPI_Comm_spawn("./processes/montecarlo", MPI_ARGV_NULL, numworkers,
            MPI_INFO_NULL,
            0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &workercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
```

How to check available slots for mpi?

This is happening in the context of a service accepting several requests:

let us suppose:Total available slots: 13

REQ1: spawn 5 processes

Req2: spawn another 5 proc

Req3:  will try to spawn 5 proc , but will crash because only 3 is available. how to check that only 3 is available?

or otherwise how to handle the crash that results from the non availability of resources. this crash is killing the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply ask `MPI_Comm_spawn()` to return with an error code instead of aborting the application.

```
MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_SELF, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
int res = MPI_Comm_spawn("./processes/montecarlo", MPI_ARGV_NULL, numworkers,
                          MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &workercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
if (MPI_SUCCESS != res) {
    // MPI_Comm_spawn failed
}
```

Comment: ok i will try this handling. is there any way to get the available slots?

Comment: you can try to get the value of the `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` attribute of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`